# React native - view config getter callback for component 'input' must be a function (received 'undefined')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to use <TextInput/> but i get this error:

> view config getter callback for component 'input' must be a function (received 'undefined'). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter

Here's the code:

```
export default function App() {
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <TextInput />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
        backgroundColor: "#F7F7F7FF",
        paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center"
    },
    header: {
        backgroundColor: "pink",
        padding: 20,
    },
});
```

The error occurs only when i use <TextInput/>

Comment: Why arent you using <TextInput> from "react-native" or "react-native-elements" ?

Comment: @Chilarai I am using "react-native" now . My IDE auto-imported component from  "react-native-web" by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is coming from the import.

```
import {TextInput} from "react-native-web";
```

This components (from react-native-web) isn't working in React Native